# How to determine if a dictionary contains a value?

Tags: c, dictionary, abstract-data-type

I'm working with some abstract data types in C and I was hoping you could help me. How would I go about figuring out if a dictionary contains a certain value? I know how to find a key using containsKey(), but how would I do the same looking for a value?

Thanks~~

Comment: You ahould use/implement a bidirectional map. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map

Answer (score 1):

Since a value can be any where in the dictionary, the only way to detect whether a value is in the dictionary is to iterate over the entries of the dictionary until you find it or you reach the end of the dictionary.

Comment: Not necessarily. It depends on what values and how the dictionary is implemented.

Comment: @lpapp, I am not following you. Can you elaborate or a provide a link that elaborates? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since Dictionary keys are unique that's why we can find any key by containsKey() function, on the other hand values can't be unique and dictionary may contain same value against every key. So only solution is to iterate over all elements until you found value or reach end of dictionary.